# How to delete a filtered range in google spreadsheet JAVASCRIPT (ERROR)

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have my code that should delete all the rows of a range by criteria but when I run this script, not all of the rows of this filtered range are deleted...
There's no error in how I get the range because I try to get the filtered range and It's ok, I get all the rows that respect criteria...

I put my code here:

```
  function eliminaRange() {
  var sourceData = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1XkYhjdQfgU7mVCR7E8mfZsf292I-cJ16PnpCimnd1v8").getSheetByName("Prova");
 var maxRows = sourceData.getMaxRows();
 var data = sourceData.getRange(1, 1, maxRows, 1).getValues();
 var date= "31/08/17";
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
 if (data[i][0] == date) {
   sourceData.deleteRow(i+1)
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: for(var i=data.length; i<=0;i--)  start at the end and work backwards to maintain index integrity

Comment: So the problem is that index's changing during "for" cicle? @ScampMichael

Comment: Correct. Every time you delete an item all the items after shift up one

Comment: Ok, thank you so much! @ScampMichael

Comment: When I run the script, It doesn't work! @ScampMichael  if (data[i][0] == date) {
   sourceData.deleteRow(i+1)   Is this correct?

Comment: for(var i=data.length; i>=0;i--)  in the previous version I had the greater than symbol (>) reversed. Does this work for you?

Comment: I put > but It doesn't work...@ScampMichael

Comment: You should probably use some tools provided by the script editor to determine why it is not working. I have run out of suggestions

Comment: @ScampMichael I opened "stackdriver Logging" and I found the error! It was here --->> if (data[i][0] == date) . deleteRow doesn't work on 2d arrays so I put --->>  if (data[i] == date)  ... and now It works well. Thank you so much for yuor help

Comment: you have learned more than just the solution to your problem. Congratulations!